# Input values not updating with nested state

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I've searched around quite a bit for this, but I'm not able to find a React Hooks example that works where the state has nested objects. I've been mostly following [this tutorial](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-build-a-react-to-do-app-with-react-hooks). I've created an example fraction calculator component, wherein I want to recalculate the result whenever either input field changes:

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';

const initialState = {
    numerator: {
        value: 1
    },
    denominator: {
        value: 2
    }
};

export const Fraction = () => {
    const [elements, setElements] = useState(initialState);

    function changeNumerator(val) {
        elements.numerator.value = parseInt(val);
        setElements(elements);
    }

    function changeDenominator(val) {
        elements.denominator.value = parseInt(val);
        setElements(elements);
    }

    function calcResult(num, denom) {
        if (denom === 0) return;
        
        return num / denom;
    }

    return <div>
        <input 
            value = {elements.numerator.value}
            onChange = {e => changeNumerator(e.target.value)}
        />

        /

        <input 
            value = {elements.denominator.value}
            onChange = {e => changeDenominator(e.target.value)}
        />

        = 

        <b>{calcResult(elements.numerator.value, elements.denominator.value)}</b>
    </div>
}
```

With this approach, the input values don't update when I change them, though the state seems to be changing (according to console logs and the React dev tools).

I thought maybe I was mutating state, so I attempted the update like this, but still no luck:

```
    function changeNumerator(val) {
        let newElements = elements;
        newElements.numerator.value = parseInt(val);
        setElements(newElements);
    }
```

What am I missing? Is it a mistake to compose state in a nested manner like this? Should `numerator` and `denominator` be broken apart? In my real-world example, the structure will be more complex; I know I could make this specific example more straightforward by not structuring the state this way, but I'm looking specifically for how to deal with nested objects, unless there's a compelling reason I should not do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

since the object pointer hasn't changed, React will not trigger another render.

change this:

```
function changeNumerator(val) {
    elements.numerator.value = parseInt(val);
    setElements(elements);
}
```

to this:

```
function changeNumerator(val) {
    setElements({
      ...elements,
      numerator: {
        value: parseInt(val, 10),
      },
    });
}
```

and do the same thing with the other function.
In this way, you create a new object, and React will recognize the change.